# Finding element where field equals a number in Play JSON

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have a JSON with the (simplified) format `"Bar":[{"name":"Foo", "amount":"20.00"}, ...]`

What do I need to do in order to find the element with the field `amount` equals to a number (e.g. `20.00`) and return the `name` field?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to use case class. I have written this small code, hope this helps.

```
// define below code in models package
case class Bar(name: String, amount: Double)

implicit val barReads: Reads[Bar] = (
(JsPath \ "name").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "amount").read[Double]
) (Bar.apply _)

// define below code in Application.scala

val jsonString =
"""
[{
 "name": "MyName1",
 "amount": 20.0
},
{
 "name": "MyName2",
 "amount": 30.0
}]
"""

val jValue = Json.parse(jsonString)

val Result = jValue.validate[Seq[Bar]].fold(errors => {
println(Json.obj("status" -> "Invalid Request!!", "message" ->    JsError.toJson(errors)) + "\n")
},
input => { //input will return Seq[Bar]
  for (i <- input) { // looping elements in Seq 
    if (i.amount == 20) {  
      println(i.name) 
    }
  }

})
```

Reference: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson